# My user is gone after changing the default shell to fish

Tags: 20.04

UBUNTU 20.04

Note: I am fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Main User: dpgomez

I changed my default shell to fish.

When I restarted, I was brought back to the Setup Menu and I was forced to make a new user, after going to the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F3 and checked if my main user "dpgomez" was still there, it was still there but after the setup which I was forced to make a new user "polgo" after rebooting I was forced to login to "Polgo". I deleted Polgo after rebooting I was back again at the Setup Menu how do I return "dpgomez" back as the main user and remove coming back to the Setup Menu

After login in via unlisted accounts the terminal also says:

```
There was an error creating child process for this Terminal
Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/fish" permission denied
```

Steps I did prior to the problem

1. I installed fish
2. Followed a guide and set fish as my default shell using this command `sudo usermode -s /usr/share/fish dpgomez`
3. I restarted my laptop
4. Open loading after the Ubuntu Loading Screen I was directed back to the Setup Menu with the Welcome/Timezone/New User
5. I made a new user then I noticed my main account was not listed so I logined using unlisted accounts
6. Upon login the terminal shows the error above `There was an error creating child process for this Terminal Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/fish" permission denied`

Comment: What is the "setup menu"?  Did you remove your installation media?  Is it possible you actually performed a new system installation over your existing one?

Comment: @Nmath Apparently not I have been using this system for about a month now, I already removed the installation media back when I finished installing Ubuntu. This started after I made fish my default shell after restarting I was directed to the Setup Menu

Comment: *"This started after I made fish my default shell after restarting"* - sounds like you found the source of your problem -- undo this change and see if your problem persists

Comment: @Nmath Also to note that after login in via unlisted accounts the terminal also says that "There was an error creating child process for this Terminal", " Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/fish" permission denied "

Comment: I tried undoing the change by changing back my default shell but the terminal outputs "You may not change the shell for 'dpgomez'"

Comment: you can always reboot and from the GRUB menu, boot from recovery -- enable networking - then drop to a root shell prompt

Comment: I tried resetting the shell using root, but after relaunching the terminal again same error goes "Failed to execute child process '/usr/share/fish'" (Permission Denied)"

Comment: I added the steps I did before the problem

Comment: @Nmath I noticed something but im not sure if this is the cause of the problem, I ran ```sudo egrep dpgomez /etc/passwd``` and I notice that dpgomez is now under Polgo
after the output ```dpgomez:x:1000:1000:Polgo:/home/dpgomez:/etc/bash```

Comment: `/usr/share/fish` is almost certainly **not** what you should have used in your `chsh -s` command (in fact it's likely a directory) - the shell itself will be at `/usr/bin/fish`. Also you must first add `/usr/bin/fish` to the list of valid login shells at `/etc/shells`.

Comment: ... and similarly, in `dpgomez:x:1000:1000:Polgo:/home/dpgomez:/etc/bash` the issue is that `/etc/bash` is not a shell, you should have used `/bin/bash`